# My screen flickers when watching video on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, video

My laptop is using Nvidia 440 proprietary drivers. I tried with open-source variant too but it is having similar issues.

Edit: This is a problem only when playing videos in a browser. I tried with Firefox and Brave, with both of them I have a flickering issue in video playing.

[image: List of available drivers]

Comment: It happens *only* in the browser? Check your browser's settings and see if you have 'hardware acceleration' enabled. If you do, disable it and restart the browser(s).

Comment: Yes, I tried. With firefox, flickering is still present but to a lesser extent. With Brave browser flickering completely stopped.

Comment: That's what I figured it was but I can't help you with Firefox as I don't use it. Maybe there's something in the advanced config that's still enabled? You can use about:config and search for acceleration to see if there's still something enabled.

Comment: I do have the same issue on a dell xps 13 2-in-1 7390. Have you found a solution? ubuntu 22.04 is my version and the browser is firefox. Not full-screen required. It does not happen when I play the video in full-screen.